Zero a matrix entry by orthogonal transformation?
I am investigating how orthogonal rotations alter the zero patterns of a matrix.
Definitions:

Denote by $\operatorname{supp}(A)$ the support matrix of a real matrix $A$, where $\operatorname{supp}(A)_{ij} = \mathbb{1}(A_{ij} \neq 0)$.

Let $ S \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n} $ be an arbitrary square support matrix with $S_{ij}=1$ at a given index $(i,j)$.

Define the set of all possible post-rotational supports with zeroing $S_{i,j}$ as:
$$\mathcal{R}(S,i,j) := \{\operatorname{supp}(AQ): A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \text{ with } \operatorname{supp}(A)=S, Q \text{ is orthogonal, } (AQ)_{ij}=0 \}.$$

In $\mathcal{R}(S,i,j)$, unintended zeros may appear when only aiming to zero the $(i,j)$ entry. The address this, we define the generic form of the post-rotational support:
$$R^*(S,i,j):= \arg\max_{S'}\{\|S'\|_1: S' \in \mathcal{R}(S,i,j)\}.$$

We need to show that $R^*(S,i,j)$ is unique and equals $\operatorname{supp}(\sum_{S'\in \mathcal{R}(S,i,j)}{S'})$.



Question:
What is the necessary and sufficient conditions on $S,i,j$ such that $R^*(S,i,j)$ differs from $S$ at exactly one entry, $(i, j)$, i.e., $ S_{ij} = 1 $ and $(R^*(S,i,j))_{ij} = 0$?
This question is of interest because it identifies when an entry can be zeroed out in the support via rotation without altering any other (non)zeros, indicating that this entry is, in a sense, "redundant."

Some thoughts:
I guess (not proved) that, since we are only concerned with supports, we may only consider rotations without reflections, i.e., orthogonal $ Q $ with $ \det(Q) = 1 $. In this case, $Q$ can be decomposed as a product of Givens rotations.
For a single Givens rotation, if we replace the "$Q$ is orthogonal" to "$Q$ is Givens" in the above definition of $\mathcal{R}(S,i,j)$, the following condition can be easily obtained:
Lemma 1: $R^*(S,i,j)$ differs from $S$ at exactly one entry, $(i, j)$, if and only if there exists a $k\neq j$ such that the columns of $S$ at $j$ and $k$ are identical, i.e., $S_{lj}=S_{lk}$ for all $l\in[1,n]$, with $S_{ij}=S_{ik} = 1$. In this case, the corresponding Givens $Q$ is
$$G = 
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
& & & j & & k & \\
\hline
& 1 & & & & & \\
& & \ddots & & & & \\
& & & \cos\theta & & -\sin\theta & \\
& & & & 1 & & \\
& & & \sin\theta & & \cos\theta & \\
& & & & & & \ddots \\
& & & & & & & 1
\end{array}$$
where $\theta = \arctan\frac{-A_{ij}}{A_{ik}}$ for the matrix $A$ with $\operatorname{supp}(A)=S$.
However, the above condition is not necessary for our final goal: there are cases where $(i,j)$ is orthogonally "redundant" for $S$ not by a single Givens rotation, but by multiple Givens rotations in a sequence. In short, I am looking for a generalization of Lemma 1 to handle such cases.

Suppose in your third case that $G_1(G_2(G_3A))$ has a zero in the desired location, where the $G_i$ are Givens rotations. Then $(G_1G_2G_3)A$ has a zero there (by associativity). That gives a single orthogonal matrix $Q = G_1 G_2 G_3$ that puts a zero where you want it. I'm not sure what else you could be asking for.

Thank you @JohnHughes I have edited the question to make it clearer.
